Remove middle 0 in string preserving trailing 0s
Similar to this question, I want to remove only middle zero's while preserving trailing zeroes:
testdata <- c("101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110")

The desired result is 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 110. My real dataset contains values from 100 to 899 and is in character format.
When I adjust the answer to the linked question, it removes trailing zeroes.
sub("([1-8])0(.*)", "\\1\\2", testdata)

returns:
"11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "11"
How can I remove only middle zeroes and leave trailing zeroes?

use ([0-9]) instead of (.*).

ahh, sub("([1-8])0([0-9])", "\\1\\2", testdata) does work! I'm not sure why though. Do you want to post an answer? Thank you :)

.* matches any number of characters, including 0.  Since you want to explicitly match the last digit, use the same kind of thing you did to match the first:
([1-8])0([0-9])


You have several options
> sub("(?<=^\\d)0", "", testdata, perl = TRUE)
 [1] "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "110"

> sub("(.)0(.)", "\\1\\2", testdata)
 [1] "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "110"

